# log4j Syslogd printing a char '^I' instead of tab

Tags: java, log4j, syslog

I am working on `syslogd` which prints a message(contains tabs,spaces etc...).When i observe the `syslogd` file in /var/log/ directory,message is not having any tabs.Instead it is printing `^I`.

Running this program on `ubuntu 10.04 LTS` and `sysklogd`.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
import org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender;

public class syslogPrinter {

    private static int sysLogFacility = SyslogAppender.LOG_LOCAL3;
    private static String syslogHost = "localhost";
    private static String layoutPattern = "%m%n";
    public static Logger log2static = Logger.getLogger(syslogPrinter.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        log2static.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout(layoutPattern);

        Appender syslogdAppender = new SyslogAppender(layout, syslogHost, sysLogFacility);

        log2static.addAppender(syslogdAppender);

        String str2 = "this is a tab: ";
        str2 = str2.concat("\t");
        str2 = str2.concat("    after space");
        log2static.error(str2);
    }

}
```

**Output is coming like**

> this is a tab: ^I    after space

***expected out put is***

> this is a tab:       after space(tab
>   space should come)

Please tell me how to print tab in the message instead of `^I`.......

Do i need to configure `syslogd.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Gnome Logfile viewer or `tail` to view syslog? If not, which tool/editor are you using to view the file? Ctrl+I is a valid control sequence for the horizontal tab character in certain terminals.

I suspect that you are using a utility that does not recognize Ctrl+I as a valid escape sequence, and you would be better off using a viewer that is meant to view syslog files.

Comment: i checking logfile through Gnome file viewer but could not able to resolve this issue.Event in gedit also ^L is coming........Can you suggest any editor............